# Triangle symbol to end remarks

Tags: symbols, ntheorem

Does anyone know how to fix this preamble in order to put triangle symbols at the end of remarks (oss, ossi and oss*) and examples (es,esi and es*) in LaTeX?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\pagestyle{plain}

\graphicspath{{./Notimportant/}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollario}
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Teorema}
\newtheorem*{prop*}{Proposizione}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{cor*}{Corollario}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{oss}[theorem]{Osservazione}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defi}[theorem]{Definizione}
\newtheorem*{defi*}{Definizione}
\newtheorem{es}[theorem]{Esempio}
\newtheorem{esi}[theorem]{Esempi}

\newtheorem*{oss*}{Osservazione}
\newtheorem{ossi}[theorem]{Osservazioni}
\newtheorem*{ossi*}{Osservazioni}

\newtheorem{notaz}[theorem]{Notazione}
\newtheorem*{notaz*}{Notazione}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{esercizio}[theorem]{Esercizio}
\newtheorem{esercizio*}{Esercizio}
```

I read all the answers already given to topics like this, but I failed in my purpose.

Comment: Why is this tagged with ntheorem when you're not using it? Ntheorem can do this, but you cannot use ntheorem along with amsthm. Choose one or the other.

Comment: Note that the starred newtheorem in amsthm translates to nonumberX theorem styles in ntheorem

Comment: Hi Fede96, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please reduce your MWE to the essentials of packages that you really need.

Comment: I don't know what tag use for this question. I'm new here and I began to use LaTeX recently. So I used those tags I thought were the most appropriate to this situation. Thank you for the answer, @daleif.

Comment: Read the ntheorem manual and then decide if you want to switch to it. I use it a lot, others don't like it.